# Does installing security updates for sharepoint change the build number?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, update, build-version

I just finished updating our staging sharepoint server to the january CU. I also installed all the server and security updates through microsoft udpates. I noticed that when I finished my build was 4797 instead of 4787.

Do I have to forgo security updates to stay on a certain build number? I was under the assumption that only the sharepoint updates from the download center would update the build number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not all SharePoint patches will change the build number. There are two factors:

1. If the schema is updated and/or if Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is updated.
2. The build number on the KB has a higher build number than the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.

These will cause the build number to not increment to the expected version and is perfectly normal.

Comment: So I should be weary of even security updates for SharePoint? I use the build number to indicate what CU I am on. So if I want to stay on a certain build I should avoid all updates beyond that release date? I see so many best practice tips to avoid any SharePoint update that doesn't affect your farm. Security updates, I believe, meet that criteria.

Comment: Always be weary of any SharePoint patch. They need testing. That said, the best way to determine installed patches is through Central Admin -> Upgrade and Migration -> Check Patch Status.